# Enabling a module for the first time via admin panel

Tags: magento2, module, admin, development, bin-magento

I have created a very simple module. I can see it listed as disabled when I check via cli `php bin/magento module:status`, but when I go to admin panel `Advanced -> Advanced` I do not see it listed there. How should I enable the module? (other than cli, via admin panel)

Comment: Accept the answer If you find it helpful, so it helps other community members.

Answer (score 1):

please run command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

After Run above command,do deployment,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Remove var folder content from root.

Now you can check your changes in adminpanel.

Comment: What does this command do?

Comment: This command do unable your module.

Comment: I am searching for a non-cli way. Becuase I might not have access to SSH (which I probably would not) in a real project.

Answer (score 1):

I think [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function will be your friend, if you don't have permission of CLI or If you don't want to use CLI.

To use this function , just simple create new file in your root server(Let's call it `custom.php`), then write below code in this file

`system('php bin/magento module:status');` // you can change it to your command

And run this script with [http://your base url/custom.php](http://your%20base%20url/custom.php)

It will gives you resulted output.